# How to install conda python packages

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to install conda python packages on all cluster machines

Comment: What is the OS that you're using?

Comment: It would be for linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `conda-pack`:

> conda-pack can be used to distribute conda environments to be used with Apache Spark jobs when deploying on Apache YARN. By bundling your environment for use with Spark, you can make use of all the libraries provided by conda, and ensure that they’re consistently provided on every node. This makes use of YARN’s resource localization by distributing environments as archives, which are then automatically unarchived on every node. In this case either the tar.gz or zip formats must be used.

Source: https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/spark.html

Comment: But what if I already have a running cluster, and I want to install a new conda package. Let's say I am invoking the `conda install` terminal command in my backend. This command will install the python package ONLY on the host where the backend code is running. How do I enable that package to get installed on every cluster machines?

Comment: After you `conda install` a package into your environment, you would then call `conda pack` to package up that environment. Then when you submit the job to spark, you include the parameter `--archives` with the path to your packaged environment. That environment will then be replicated on each machine in the cluster.  Check out [the example in the docs](https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/spark.html#python-example) for more details.